# UIkit Modal Alert JS

Tags: javascript, getuikit

I use the version of UIkit 3.1.6, in JS I call the UIkit.modal.alert function, but I would like to be able to set some parameters in the modal window, I would like it in the center and with the bg-close and esc-close function set on false.
With the Uikit 2 version it worked now no, can you help me understand where I'm wrong?

```
UIkit.modal.alert("test", {bg-close: false, esc-close: false}).then(function () {
   window.location = '/test';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

"Modal dialogs" ==> number of **prepared** modal dialogs.

"prepared" = No way to send properties to `Modal dialogs` (Yet). Maybe open the GitHub issue about this topic.

https://getuikit.com/docs/modal#modal-dialogs

By code you can get the same idea/result ("do something if the modal is close")

```js
var $modal = UIkit.modal('#my-id', {
  escClose: false,
  bgClose: false
});

/* show modal */
$modal.show();

/* modal hide event */
UIkit.util.on('#my-id', 'hide', function () {
  //console.log("do something");
  UIkit.notification('Card has been moved.', 'success');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.3.1/dist/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- This is the modal -->
  <div id="my-id" uk-modal>
      <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
          <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Hello modal</h2>
          <button class="uk-modal-close" type="button">Confirm</button>
      </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.3.1/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
```